# Issues with method consistency in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, synchronization, enumeration

I really don't know squat about java memory management, so this is entirely my fault, I just need to be pointed in the direction of a solution.

I'm working with a huge dataset. I have a method that takes a string as input and returns a value. That value is based on the content of the string. If I do this on a slow, granular, one time basis:

```
while (!input.equals("#")) {

        System.out.print("Input input (logical redundancy): ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = scan.nextLine();

        Analyzer analysis = new Analyzer(new Dictionary());
        System.out.println(analysis.analyzeString(input));
    }
```

there are no issues and it is perfectly consistent. A `Dictionary` object is an array list with key-pair information for certain words.

However, if I attempt to apply that method on a bigger, enumerating scale, then I get bad data returned from the analyze method. In terms of scale, the values are in the right range, however they do not correspond to the strings that they are supposed to. The returned data, to my eye at least, is simply random. I've tried various ways of attempting the enumeration, but this is what I have right now:

```
while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getRow();
            Analyzer analysis = new Analyzer(dict);
            String entry = rs.getString(5);
            double val = analysis.analyzeString(entry);
            pst.setDouble(1, val);
            pst.setInt(2, id);
            System.out.println(val + " : " + rs.getString(5));
            pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

In that attempt, there is an extreme inconsistency with the results returned from the `analyzeString` method, even if the same string is inputted. How can I fix the inconsistency? Does it have to do with synchronization?

Comment: What is the type of rs? If it's a `Scanner`, then your problem might simply be `nextLine` vs. `getString`?

Comment: can you post your `analyzeString()` method?

Comment: A few questions: Is rs a Scanner? Why not allocate a new Dictionary in each loop iteration in the second example like you did in the first? Are multiple threads accessing anything that might cause synchronization errors?

Comment: @DZittersteyn `rs` is a ResultSet. @Hunter No, I really don't feel comfortable doing that. Essentially what it does it look up substrings in the string for keywords and returns their frequency. @cabbagebot `rs` is a ResultSet, I'm accessing this data through a MySQL database. The dictionary file takes like 2 seconds to generate, so in the interest of efficiency I don't create a new one. Maybe I should make the dictionary class final?

Comment: Have you single stepped through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug your code I suggest you step through you code with you debugger. In an IDE its the button next to run.

---

> I really don't know squat about java memory management,

I suspect it has nothing to do with it anyway.

> How can I fix the inconsistency?

Clarify what you mean by inconsistency. That could mean anything. Until you have a good idea of what the problem is, it makes it very hard to fix it.

> Does it have to do with synchronization?

Its your code. If tyou don't know nobody does. I suspect not.

BTW: I assume `pst` and `rs` have nothing to do with on another. ;)

Comment: I've updated the question with a better description of what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, please define inconsistency. I presume you mean, you are getting values not expected. If so, please print the inputs and outputs in the loop and see if you are passing what you think you are passing. I see that you are passing value of the 5th column of the query results. `Did you remember that it is not 0-based index, but 1-based index`?

Secondly, is it possible to keep the Analyzer instantiation outside the loop?

```
Analyzer analysis = new Analyzer(dict);
while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getRow();

            String entry = rs.getString("Use_Column_name_Here_to_be_SAFE");
            double val = analysis.analyzeString(entry);
            pst.setDouble(1, val);
            pst.setInt(2, id);
            System.out.println(id+": "+ val + " : " + entry);
            pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: If I create the `Analyzer` outside of the loop then the values returned just become a running sum, which is odd, because in the `analyzeString()` method, I reset all the variables involved in the final value to 0. Here's an example of what happens: `8072: -229.76000000000022
8073: -229.3600000000002
8074: -229.56000000000023` I witheld the values.

Comment: Single step the code and check what you are getting. May be there is a bug in your Analyzer. It does not work as expected.